# Forcing all content into 2nd column

Tags: spacing, columns

I'm working in landscape,twocolumn mode and am using Latex to make a programme for an upcoming event. Since it is the outside of the programme I need the cover info to only be on the right hand side of the page. I've tried using `\vspace*`, `\vfill` and even `\bigskip` but to no avail, it doesn't seem to want to work :/

Also, sorry for not posting my inputs, but I'm not very familiar with the site and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Start your first column out with `\mbox{}\columnbreak` and leave an empty line before you start your bidniz.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You should get to the habit of writing [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) `:)`

Comment: Thanks! I ended up doing a workaround where I just altered my borders until I got everything in the right position. I'll remember that for next time though!

Comment: With the `paracol` package you could handle the columns independently.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to tinker seems to be a booklet. I produce programms usually this way:

I have four pages: the title pages, followed by two pages of my programm, and on the last pages things like fee for the tickets, sponsors, and the like. Just take your usual papersize, I use DIN A4.

After you've got a PDF of four pages, use ["pdfbook"](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/pdfjam?lang=en) with this command:

```
pdfbook --preamble '\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1'  Programm.pdf -o Programm-booklet.pdf
```

The LaTeX command is necessary because some fonts (or only Linux Libertine?) show little squares instead of letters after compiling into the booklet.